# creating a vsam file using jcl

Tags: jcl, vsam

I am trying to create a **VSAM** file using **IDCAMS** utility in *JCL. MAXCC code*  that it returns is 0000.

But the newly created vsam file is not displayed in the list when I try to list it using 3.4.

Can anyone help me on this.?

The code that I have used is :

```
//VSAM0001 JOB (ACCT),CLASS=A,MSGLEVEL=(1,1
//             NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGCLASS=A   
//STEP0001 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                 
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                    
//SYSIN    DD  *                           
    DEFINE CLUSTER -                       
       (NAME(DOMAIN.MYFILE.MYVSAM) -   
       VOL(AGH419) -                   
       KEYS(16 0) -                    
       RECORDSIZE(120 120) -           
       INDEXED -                       
       REUSE ) -                       
    DATA -                                 
      (NAME(DOMAIN.MYFILE.MYVSAM.DATA) - 
      CISZ(8192) -                      
      RECORDSIZE(120 120) -             
      FSPC(0 0) ) -                     
    INDEX -                                
      (NAME(DOMAIN.MYFILE.MYVSAM.INDEX) )
/*
```

Comment: It would help to give us the instructions you used. Otherwise, I could only guess, which is not a good problem-solving exercise.

Comment: Please show your IDCAMS control statements and any messages displayed in SYSPRINT or JESMSGLG when you run your job.

Comment: The message displayed in SYSPRINT is: INCORRECT SPECIFICATION OF SPACE ALLOCATION

Comment: The message ID is always important. Always include it. Try poking the message reference into IBM's LookAt web service and seeing what it says.

Comment: where to include message ID? I am not aware of it.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. IBM's LookAt utility helped. I have not specified the CYL parameter which is required because of which I have got the INCORRECT SPECIFICATION OF SPACE ALLOCATION.Now it is working.

Comment: Always try to copy some control cards which already work. It'll save problems like this. When you get an error message, look it up. There are lots of Messages and Codes manuals, so IBM's LookAt is very useful as it finds the correct manual for you and extracts the message. Don't try that with COBOL, though. COBOL error messages are self-explanatory.

Comment: @KinjalShah can you put your findings as an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: While creating the VSAM file using IDCAMS utility in JCL, you need to supply the disk storage paraeters.

Answer (score 3):

While creating VSAM file using IDCAMS utility, you need to specify all the storage parameters that are required like CYL, TRK etc..If you miss out any of these parameters then JCL won't be able to know where to store the newly created VSAM. So, in **DEFINE** portion of your JCL file, supply all the necessary storage parameters and you are good to go. :) Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 1):

As the author wrote in the comments:

> Thank you all for the response. IBM's LookAt utility helped. I have not specified the CYL parameter which is required because of which I have got the INCORRECT SPECIFICATION OF SPACE ALLOCATION.Now it is working. –  Kinjal Shah

Answer (score 0):

All messages will have an id (e.g., IEA1235) that can be used when searching for what generated the message.

You need to specify space in your IDCAMS 'DEFINE'.  Look in your manual (or online) for specifying space for VSAM clusters.